# How can I delete image from drive when delete a row of database in laravel 6.9?

Tags: php, laravel, image

I want to delete image when I delete a row with a information of a student

here is the uploaded code i used. i also used intervention/image package for resize

```
if (request()->has('image')) {
    $photo = request()->file('image');
    $image = Image::make($req->image)->resize(413, 513)->save(public_path('../../students/' . DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId().'png'));

    DB::table('students')
        ->where('id','=', DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId())
        ->update([
            'image'=> DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId().'.png',
        ]);
}
```

and here is the delete row code

```
public function destroyStudentProfile(Request $request)
{
    DB::table('students')
        ->where('id', '=', $request->std_id)
        ->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.student')->with('message', "The Profile of id=".$request->std_id." has been Delete !");
}
```

now i want to add a line for delete image from my folder. now what can I do?

Comment: Well create the same file system path again, as you did when you stored the file - and then use `unlink` …?

Comment: Call to undefined method Faker\Provider\File::delete()
please help me for that.
i used this code
`
        $image = DB::table('students')->where('id', $request->std_id)->first();
        $file= $image->image;
        $filename = public_path().'/../../students'.$file;
        File::delete($filename);
`

Comment: unlink('file_path');

Comment: thanks all. it worked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those as Eloquent Models? You can use the [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events)

```php
model::deleted(function($model){

    // Write your code here to run on `deleted` event

}
```

---

#### Events are

`retrieved`, `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `restoring`, `restored`

---

#### To delete a file from the server you can either use the

```php
Storage::disk('your_disk')->delete(IMAGE_PATH);
```

or

```php
unlink(IMAGE_PATH);
```